# Preparation for data scientist interviews for final year PhD student

Tags: career-path, job-search, job, data-science

I would like to check/ask if there is anything particular that I need to prepare for data scientist interviews. I am quite unsure/lost about the requirements since I am coming from academia (see my background in the next paragraph), and am also working on a tight timeline. I am hoping to transition into an industry data science role -- the aim is to leave academia for good. Thank you for the advice.

**My background:** I am currently a final year PhD student in machine learning where my research is on machine learning theory, so there is little coding and a lot of designing and analyzing algorithms (i.e., math). I have never interned or worked in the industry before (went directly into my PhD program after my undergrad). I am familiar with most machine learning algorithms (having taken both undergrad and graduate level courses on the topic), however since I worked in theory, I don't have any experience applying ML algorithms to real datasets (mainly just analyzed algorithms mathematically).

Also, it is advisable to go into interviews without any (technical) prep given my background -- asking in the worst case if the timing is too tight for me. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll want to make sure you can load data from a file and do some basic manipulations live-- averaging, groupbys, making plots. Usually in a jupyter notebook with pandas. It's unlikely you'll be asked to code a model, just conceptual questions. kaggle is a good place to practice.

Comment: Hi. I think this is not the right community for your question. Maybe Data Science SE can provide you better answers? https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Workplace SE is probably more appropriate for this question.

Comment: I'd recommend using your remaining time to beef up on your software development skills. Python, R, for starters.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the strength of your case is that you are up to date on what is known, theoretically, about your field and the weakness is that you have little practical, applied, experience. That will be obvious from your CV, I'd also guess. It isn't something you can hide or finesse.

I'd suggest, therefore, that in any interviews you try to emphasize the strengths and indicate that you are looking forward to putting that theory to work effectively. I'd be careful *not* to say that you want to emphasize theoretical developments in the field, but, rather, the practical elements. Indicate also that you are a good person to stay current with the theory as necessary, though.

Your background is what it is. Some places will like that, others won't. But that is the case for just about everyone.

---

Earlier in your studies you might have been able to do an internship of some sort, but it seems late to be able to change the record at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.